# Inset Map in Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I haven't been able to find this answer in the Maps API documentation, but is it possible to have an "inset" map using the Google Maps API?

It seems like it is doable with the [Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/) (see lower left corner), but you can't customize the map with this API.

Comment: Are you looking for an [Overview Map Control](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-v3-overviewmapcontrol/)? [Native Google Maps Javascript API v3 Overview Map Control](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#OverviewMapControlOptions)

Comment: @geocodezip Yeah, sort of. I like how it is displayed in Maps Embed API (lower left corner). As you move the basemap, you can also see the inset map (lower left corner) move, which displays the satellite imagery. I've been looking into this and have noticed that if I have `signed_in=true` in my Maps API url, I can get a UI similar to Embed API. It's weird that they have 2 different UIs based on whether you use `signed_in=true` or not.

Comment: @geocodezip I figured it out. See my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up making my own. I don't know why this question was downvoted. Anyway, check out my JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wLuhktu4/1/

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 17,
        center: {
            lat: -33.8666,
            lng: 151.1958
        },
        disableDefaultUI: true
    };
    var overviewMapOptions = {
        zoom: 17,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
        center: {
            lat: -33.8666,
            lng: 151.1958
        },
        disableDefaultUI: true
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    var overviewMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('overview-map'), overviewMapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', (function () {
        overviewMap.setCenter(map.getCenter());
        overviewMap.setZoom(map.getZoom());
    }));
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

The problem (although minor) is that because this is not officially supported, the watermark and terms of use take up a lot of space on this inset map.

I hope this helps someone in the future.